# How to turn OFF "human readable" dates in github?

Tags: sorting, github

Or better, get them all in the same units.  I am human, but those dates; to me "4 years ago" scans as a shorter time than "28 days ago" unless I really concentrate.

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: I don't think this is the right forum for asking how to customize your GitHub profile. This is meant for programming questions. You're most likely to get some downvotes.

Comment: This would be more applicable on [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com). I've voted to have it moved.